# PPT Slide Reset but maintain bold

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have slides with various text and bulleted lists on them.  I want to use the "Reset" button to apply the current Master Slide formatting to them (to fix bullets, change to default color, etc.).

When I Reset the slide everything works well except if I previously had bolded text, I lose it.  How can I perform the reset, but maintain any bold text.

My slides are created programatically, so eventually I will be performing this slide reset programatically too; however, I want to maintain any bold text, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Reset is supposed to do exactly what you've described. To bring the slide back into line with what the layout dictates *without* removing your text formatting overrides (bolding, etc) simply apply the original layout again.

Answer (score 0):

I suffer from the same issue. I add local formatting - Subtitles, bold, italics etc and then a colleague moves the title around.

If I click slide reset the title pops back into place but I lose all local formatting as well.

According to another youtube clip I watched - the correct answer is to select slide layout and pick the same layout that is already picked. Title resets and I keep local formatting.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1207013)